# double returning only one precision in java

Tags: java

in my code i am performing division on numbers and storing it in a double variable. but the variable is returning with only one precision. i want to increase the precision how could i do that.

```
double x;
        for ( int i =0 ; i<10000 ; i++)
        {

            x= w[i] / l[i];
            System.out.println(x);
        }
```

in the above code w and l are integer arrays;

i am getting output like

```
3.0
0.0
1.0
0.0
```

i want to increase the precision upto 4 atleast.

Comment: Java uses floating point, there is no such thing as setting the percision. Your bug is that you're dividing integers by integers (yielding an integer result), and assigning a double to that result. Try changing `x = w[i] / l[i]` to `x = (double) w[i] / l[i]`.

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
x = ((double) w[i]) / l[i];
```

As it is, you're dividing two integers using integer division, and assigning the resulting int to a double. Casting one of the operands to a double makes it do a double division instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you divide an `int` by another `int` you get an `int` not a double.  Try

```
x = (double) w[i] / l[i];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
System.out.printf("%10.4f", x);
```

Mind, only BigDecimal has precise precision. Doubles are approximations.

Comment: You've missed the actual problem here.

Comment: @EJP yes, those integral results were suspiciously enough. The primary integral division error and its double cast solution was already given as answer though.